# Undesired side effect of SortBy

Tags: sorting

After long searching, I noticed that the SortBy[list,f] function has an annoying side effect: If the function f yields the same value for consecutive elements of the list, those are still sorted using the canonical ordering of the elements. This is very annoying - I want to sort only on the first element of a list but leave the order of list elements unchanged if the first element is not changing. How can this be achieved?

e.g.:

```
    y1 = {{1., 2.}, {1., 1.}, {3., 2.}}
    SortBy[y1, #[[1]] &]
```

Gives:

```
    {{1.,1.},{1.,2.},{3.,2.}}
```

But I would like to obtain:

```
    {{1.,2.},{1.,1.},{3.,2.}}
```

Comment: I can verify this, MMA 12.3 Windows

Comment: Or, even better, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3304632, which was referenced in the question cited by @LeonidShifrin

Answer (score 9):

```
SortBy[y1, {#[[1]] &}]
```

> ```
> {{1., 2.}, {1., 1.}, {3., 2.}}
> ```

Comment: Nice - thanks! Too bad that this is not better described in Help.

Comment: Or you can use `SortBy[y1, {#[[1]] &, Nothing}]` or `SortBy[y1, {#[[1]] &, #[[1]] &}]` if you need to have multiple explicit functions in the second argument.